# get Children of Layer that are circles and have specific ID in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to extract all circles from a KineticJs layer that have a either of two predifined id's. Every circle has an Id unique when created and added on layer. So my code is the following

```
var id1 = "ID1";
var id2 = "ID2";
var _point;
_point = backgroundLayer.getChildren(function (node){
    return node.getClassName() === 'Circle' && (node.getId() === id1 || node.getId() === id2;

}
```

But point always has all Circle objects on my layer, meaning that the expression returns always true. Am I missing something? I also get a funny result. I tried to copy the result of the logical expression and instead of true or false I get one of the two values of id1 or id2. E.g(from console)

```
console.log(node.getId()+ "=== "+id1+" || "+node.getId()+ " === " +id2);
console.log(node.getId() === id1 || node.getId() === id2);


//actual result from my code
startPoint === P || startPoint === Or //expression P and Or are values for id1 and id2 respectively
Or //result
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: It was probably something that wasn't right on my code, I rewrote it and works. Guess there was a spelling mistake that created this logical error